# are we able to get precise battery level in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-wifi, batterylevel, 3g-network

I'm aware that this question was asked before. but the answer redirected to Battery Manager API.

What I was hoping for was a method to know the draining rate per second.

any of you guys know how to get the draining rate per second?
 I understand that WIFI and mobile data have different power consumption is there any way to find it?

Thank you.

Comment: if nothing else, capture the current battery level for some fixed intervals, and then calculate the difference per time period.

Comment: There is nothing in the Android SDK for this. Some people have used various Linux approaches, AFAIK, but the further you get outside the SDK boundaries, the more likely it is you will run into per-device issues.

Comment: Hi Marc, the battery Manager allows us to get the battery life by only 1% significance. however the draining rate is too slow(1% per 5-10 minutes). I want the code to be part of my app so it'll slow down my app.

Comment: so, is there any way to get at least battery usage of networks like 3G and Wifi specifically.  ?

Comment: No, there is not.  Furthermore, you are likely imagining far more accuracy in the percentage capacity report than there really is.

Comment: what about http://source.android.com/devices/tech/power.html where   battery.capacity is there andwifi.on,wifi.active are there, but how to use them any Ideas?